# Master detail field is blank on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, custom-field, fields, master-detail

I have a page that should allow me to select a case number from a master detail field but when the page is loaded the field is not there, only the label. I have tried to add an additional look-up field for a test that points to the same place and works just fine.  Any ideas or suggestions?

```
      <apex:page standardController="Case_Note__c" recordSetVar="MassAddCaseNotes" tabStyle="Case_Note__c" extensions="MassAddCaseNotes">

    <apex:sectionHeader title="Mass Add Case Notes" />      
    <apex:form > 

        <apex:pageBlock title="Case Notes" >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSave" immediate="false" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveandclose}" value="Save and Close" status="retrieveSaveStatus" id="btnSaveClose" immediate="false" />

            </apex:pageBlockButtons>                                        
            <apex:actionStatus layout="block" startText="Saving notes. . . " stopText="" id="retrieveSaveStatus" startStyle="color:green; font-style:italic" stopStyle="color:black;"/>

            <apex:pageMessages showDetail="false" />
            <br/> 
            <apex:outputText value="Enter Notes to submit to cases then select cases the notes will be submitted to." style="font-style:italic" /><br/>             
            <br/>



<apex:pageBlockSection title="Enter Your Notes: " columns="1">
            <apex:outputLabel for="CaseNote"> </apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:inputField style="width:300px;height:100px" value="{!Case_Notes.Note__c}" id="CaseNote"  />
           </apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Date: " columns="1">
                        <apex:outputLabel for="Date"> </apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Date__c}" id="Date" />
             </apex:pageBlockSection>

<apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Case: " columns="1">
                        <apex:outputLabel for="case"> </apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Case_Notes.Case__c}" id="case" />
             </apex:pageBlockSection>


<apex:pageBlockSection title="Select Contacts To Add Notes To: " columns="1">
                        <apex:outputLabel for="ContactName1"> </apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:inputfield value="{!Case_Notes.Contact_Name__c}" />

             </apex:pageBlockSection>


           </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

This is the rest of my code.

```
public class MassAddCaseNotes {


public Case_Note__c Case_Notes      {get; set;}

public MassAddCaseNotes (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) 
{
Case_Note__c note= new Case_Note__c();
}


public PageReference save() 
{
    Case_Note__c note= new Case_Note__c(
    Note__c= Case_Notes.Note__c,
    Contact_Name__c= Case_Notes.Contact_Name__c,
    Date__c= Case_Notes.Date__c,
    Case__c= Case_Notes.Case__c
    );            

insert note;

 PageReference pg = new PageReference('/');
        pg.setRedirect(true);
        return pg;
}



public PageReference saveandclose() 
{
return null;
}



}
```

Comment: Could you add your code please?

Comment: Still need more code after the edit. We'd like to see what your controller is for the page, and if it is a custom controller, do you have a proper getter to populate the value on page load, for example.

Comment: paste the complete page please!!!!

Comment: That is the complete page. That is all the code I have written.

Comment: What is your Master object and do you have permission on that object?

Comment: The master object is Cases. I do have permissions to this object.

Comment: You're missing the `<apex:page>` from the top of the Visualforce. As @greenstork says, it's hard to give a definitive answer without all the code.

Comment: I thought all of the visualforce page was pasted in. I guess some got cut off in the process. All of the code should be there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to create a `Case_Note__c` in your constructor. Currently your fields on your visualforce are backed by a null object.

Code:

```
public MassAddCaseNotes (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
    Case_Note__c note= new Case_Note__c();
}
```

You don't need to save the object, but you do have to have it created to use the lookup, I believe.

Comment: I added the line of code to my constructor and is still showing only the label and not the lookup field. I have verified that I do have permissions to the master object. I also edited the code above to reflect what I now have.

Comment: I added something just a little bit different than what you posted. I added Case_Notes = new Case_Note__c();   this is what ended up working. Thank you for the help though. I really appreciate it.